# Pick records since last particular day of week

Tags: mysql

I want to pick and SUM values since last wednesday until NOW() in mysql. How can I do that?

Sorry for incomplete question, by the last Wednesday I did not mean to hard-code the date, rather I want my program to run that query, so it cannot hard-code--- Needs a flexible solution. Please help...

Comment: It's probably easiest and most efficient to compute "last wednesday"'s date in your application, then just run a straight `WHERE datecol > '2011-07-20'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genesis is right (He's very right, use his suggestion), but as an intellectual exercise: This is the best pure MySQL I could think of:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
   WHERE 
     DATE_COLUMN > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + 3 DAY);
```

NOW - DAYOFWEEK => this past Saturday. Weds. is three days before that.

Comment: Hi this solution is right. But one problem, It picks the records since the wednesday before the last wednesday. I guess the problem lies in + 3 DAY. I tried to correct it but it gives me a lot of syntax errors

Comment: Actually DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) + 3 DAY) returns 9. Thus 9 days are subtraced from today.. Please help..

Comment: That is correct. Two days ago was Wednesday, and that is the Wednesday before. You could do - 4 instead and that would be this immediately past Wednesday

Comment: Doesn't work on Thursday, Friday or Saturday (when I think the OP wants the expression to return yesterday, the day before, or two days before respectively)

Answer (score 2):

```
select date_sub(now(), interval dayofweek(date_sub(now(), interval 4 day)) day);
```

This works on any day of the week and always returns the Wednesday which has most recently passed. On a Wednesday itself, it returns the previous Wednesday. The next day, it returns yesterday

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM table WHERE date > '2011-07-20'
```

You should calculate your date from your programming language (fastest solution)

Comment: Very easy, I did not accepted your answer and you just downvoted this post.

But tbh, please tell me yourself, did your answer helped at all? If you have to do everything in programming language then why DBMSs are made, just save your data in text files? Huh